# MVC 5 Entity Framework Filter Results Based Off Combo From Different Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have found examples of filtering results from a drop down... but in all the examples I've found the drop downs use the same model as the results. I've attempted to throw the drop down in a partial view with one model and the results in another view with a different model... but it didn't work. This would be very simple in PHP, or WinForms, or MS Access but in MVC it seems very complex to do something so simple.

My models are simple. I have Contacts which can be assigned to Groups with a bridge table/ object ContactGroups:

```
public class Contacts
{
    public int ContactsID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Primary Phone")]
    [Phone]
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Type")]
    public PhoneType PhoneType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PrimaryEmail")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MessageContacts> MessageContacts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactGroups> ContactGroups { get; set; }
}



public class Groups
{
    public int GroupsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactGroups> ContactGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ContactGroups
{
    public int ContactGroupsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to populate the drop down with available groups and filter all contacts who are in the groups from the drop down selection. I imagine this is probably simple for you who are experienced with EF so I am very appreciative of your help!

Comment: @AntDC Is that the standard way an MVC developer would do it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.
I had to have a cascading form where I select from one drop down and this choice decided the contents of the next and so on.  I found it worked for me.

I'm from Application development background so I feel your pain.

Comment: That's a common pattern. Something like [this](http://jnye.co/Posts/12/creating-cascading-dropdownlists-using-mvc-4-and-jquery).

Comment: @SteveGreene that was a nice example and I believe exactly what I need. The example had static data but should still apply I believe. If you post this as an answer I'll award it and then post the final solution based off of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notes that POHeaderId drop down choices are populated in the documenmt ready...
So, once they select a POheaderID it populates the OldLocation wit the relevent choices as per returned by the action.

Here's an outline - maybe you can do a similar thing or may be you find a more suitable solution.

Part of view...

```
<div class="form-group form-group-no-bott-marg">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoHeaderId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("PoHeaderId", String.Empty)
        @Html.Label("NB: XXXXXX moved by specific Purchase Order", new { style = "color: red" })
    </div>    
</div>        
<div class="form-group form-group-no-bott-marg">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldLocationId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("OldLocationId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldLocationId)
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of javascript......for when the POHader is changed.....

```
$('#PoHeaderId').change(function() {
    $('#confirm').text('');
    var poId = $("#PoHeaderId :selected").val();

var items = [];
//Call the action to get the list in JSON format
var url = "@Url.Action("Locations", "Utilities")";
//alert(url);
window.ShowOrHideProgress(true);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: { locationId: 0, poHeaderId: poId },
    success: function (resultantJsonData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resultantJsonData.length; i++) {
            items.push("<option value=" + resultantJsonData[i].Value + ">" + resultantJsonData[i].Text + "</option>");
        }
        $('#OldLocationId').html(items.join(' '));
    }
});
```

});

The action it calls.....

```
public ActionResult Locations(int locationId, int poHeaderId = 0)
{
    var locList = StockMovesHeaderViewModelHelper.GetLocations(db, locationId, poHeaderId);

    var tmpList = new SelectListWithSelect(true);
    foreach (var l in locList)
    {
        tmpList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = l.Description, Value = l.FulfilmentLocationID.ToString() });
    }
    return Json(tmpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In looking at this it seems you have two dropdowns that are populating with different columns... but with the same model. The main issue I am having is that my models are different

Comment: Yes - but I am sure you can tweek and use it with some partial views etc
Good luck.